# Why does my JScrollPane open small?

Tags: jscrollpane, sizing

My JScrollPane opens but very small.  I have tried using setPreferredSize on both the JTextArea as well as the JScrollPane but still when I add the JScrollPane to my FlowLayout panel it opens very small.  Without the JScrollPane my JTextArea opens to the correct size.  With the JScrollPane I get a very small JTextArea.  Also, trying to setBorder just causes my program to hang.  Any help would be appreciated. (I am using Netbeans 8.0.1)

Code outtakes:

```
    // Create the array manipulator display using JTextArea
    JTextArea display = new JTextArea(5, 40);

    //private final JScrollPane displayScroller;
    JScrollPane displayScroller = new JScrollPane();

    // Create arrays for the dimensions of the buttons and displays
    int[] dimW ={300, 45, 100, 90, 190, 240, 500};
    int[] dimH = {35, 40, 10};

    // Declare and initialize the dimensions for the components
    Dimension displayDimension = new Dimension(dimW[1], dimH[0]);

     // Establish variable for Window and Panel Layout
    FlowLayout f1 = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER);

     row[0] = new JPanel();

     row[0].setLayout(f1);

     // Create Array Manipulator display area
    display.setFont(font);
    display.setEditable(false);
    display.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
    display.setPreferredSize(displayDimension);
    display.setLineWrap(true);
    display.setWrapStyleWord(true);

    // Create display area scroller
    displayScroller = new JScrollPane(display);
    displayScroller.setPreferredSize(displayDimension);

    row[0].add(displayScroller);
    add(row[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I see that my setPreferredSize options were very small which is why the JScrollPane was opening small.  My JTextArea was using the same displayDimension but earlier when I created the JTextArea I established a larger size for the JTextArea.  For some unknown reason, my JTextArea was not accepting the newer setPreferredSize and was maintaining the size established during instantiation.  I adjusted the size of my JScrollPane using;

```
  displayScroller.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(640,90));
```

It is working fine now.